# Rails 3 + passenger conf file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, .htaccess, passenger

I have been trying to install a rails app on a box that originally was used for multiple php applications.  I installed passenger and created a conf file but I am confused about how it all works together.

What should my ServerName be if i want to access a Rails app? The box is a debian squeeze running apache2 with passenger module installed. Below is my conf file. I currently have to go to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/leoadmin/public to get the application to run properly. I have the following htaccess in the public directory. Which I think is unnecessary if my conf file is configured correctly.

I think my main issue is the misconfiguration of the conf file. I believe the conf file is being loaded but i don't understand why i still need the htaccess for me to see any action.

.htaccess

```
#PassengerEnabled On
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/leoadmin/
#Options -MultiViews
#PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Set this to whatever environment you'll be running in
RailsEnv production
#RackBaseURI /var/www/leoadmin
```

vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerName leoadmin

    DocumentRoot /var/www/leoadmin/public
    <Directory /var/www/leoadmin/public>
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /leoadmin /var/www/leoadmin/public
    <Location /leoadmin>
            SetEnv RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT "/leoadmin"
            PassengerAppRoot /var/www/leoadmin
    </Location>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/leoadmin-error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/leoadmin-access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had nothing but pain and more pain trying to get this sorted a few months back, my configuration allows me to do sub URIs, so I'm not sure if that's what you want, but it'll be along these lines. I've never needed a `.htaccess` file for this setup:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.test.co.uk
DocumentRoot /web/rails
<Directory /web/rails>
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RailsBaseURI /test
RailsEnv development
<Directory /web/rails_projects/test/>
    Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

For me `/web/rails` is a root directory, from there I have a number of symlinks to my `/home/` directory where I store my projects. ServerName is whatever qualified name you're using for the machine that's going to be recognised.

(just in case, I'm running Passenger 3.0.9, and Rails 3.2.11)

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, I see you have you server name set to a publicly accessibly domain. What would my servername be if my box isn't publicly accessible? Does it matter?

Comment: I've copied that from an example I wrote for a blog post, I imagine you can get away with using leoadmin or leoadmin.local as long as the server will respond to the domain.